# splitting a string with parentheses and commas into smaller variables using sscanf

Tags: c, string, variables, scanf

I have a file that contains multiple lines with the following format:

```
 2019-12-05 07:14:00 (151.45,-23.917)
```

I want to split each line into 3 variables so that the first variable is "2019-12-05", the second variable is "07:14:00" and the final variable is (151.45,-23.917) in the example of the above line shown.

I have a snippet of code below in which I tried to split the lines into three variables but I get a segmentation fault.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE    *fp=NULL;
    char inpFname[81],buf[8000];
    int dates,hour,lon,lat; 
    int i=0;
    int voyageid = atoi(argv[1]);

    sprintf(inpFname,"%d_latlon.txt",voyageid);

    if ((fp=fopen(inpFname,"rt"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nERROR: Cannot open/read input file [%s]\n\n",inpFname);
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(buf,8000,fp);
        printf("%d) buf is %s",i,buf);
        sscanf(buf,"%s %s %s", dates,hour,lon);
        printf("date is %s and lat is %s and lon is %s\n",dates,lat,lon);
        i=i+1;  
    }

}
```

How can I tweak the code to ensure a successful split of each line into separate variables?

The file being input looks like this:

```
2019-12-03 06:00:00 (152.282,-13.505)
2019-12-03 12:00:00 (152.393,-14.8478)
2019-12-03 18:00:00 (152.505,-16.1906)
2019-12-04 00:00:00 (152.618,-17.5335)
2019-12-04 06:00:00 (152.732,-18.8763)
2019-12-04 12:00:00 (152.846,-20.2191)
2019-12-04 18:00:00 (152.962,-21.5619)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't possibly tell why a seg fault occurs if we don't know how all the buffers and variables are defined and set.

Comment: For starters, always check the function return values. Particularly `sscanf` in this case. Should not blindly attempt to print the string values if `sscanf` fails to parse any of them. That may seg fault depending on how those variables were defined and initialised.

Comment: How are `dates`, `hour`, and `lon` declared?

Comment: `int dates`? You need char buffers because that's what you are telling `sscanf` is being provided with `%s`.

Comment: If that code doesn't scream warnings at you, you seriously need to turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors. You're asking  to parse three strings, the mandate for `%s` is to provide a target `char` buffer sufficiently sized to accept the incoming data plus terminator. You're passing three `int` values rather than three `char `buffer addresses. So.. undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. You need to declare `dates`, `hour`, `lon`, and `lat` as *strings*, because that's what `%s` in `fscanf` expects.

That's your main problem, but while you're at it, you should fix two other things which will be causing you other problems soon enough:

2. You need to check the return value from `fscanf`.
3. You need to not call `while(!feof(fp))`.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).)  Once you're checking the return value from `fscanf`, you should use it to terminate your loop, if `fscanf` returns less than the number of items you ask for, 3 or 4.

Your next question will be, how do you declare `dates`, etc. as strings?  If you do something like

```
char *dates;
```

that'll fail, too, because `dates` doesn't point anywhere yet.  Easier would be

```
char dates[100];
```

or, if you want to use pointers, you can retain `char *dates`, as long as you then do something like

```
dates = malloc(100);
```

followed by a check to make sure `malloc` didn't return NULL.  And then, in either case, for safety, you should change the relevant part of the format string to be `%99s`, to make sure `fscanf` doesn't try to read more into the string than it can hold (and where you use `%99s`, not `%100s`, because you have to leave space for the `\0` terminator).

And then your next question will be, if `dates` and the rest are strings, how can you pull the numbers out of them?  Functions like `atoi`, `atof`, `strtol`, and `strtod` may help, or extra/different `scanf` formats.

For example, you could do something like

```
int y, m, d;
if(sscanf(dates, "%d-%d-%d", &y, &m, &d) == 3) {
    /* now have broken-down date in y, m, d *.
}
```

Of, you could do a completely different top-level parse:

```
int year, month, day, hour, minute, second;
double lat, lon;

while(fscanf(fp, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d (%lf,%lf)", year, month, day, hour, minute, second, &lat, &lon) == 8) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If the string you're trying to parse is a date/time, you're better off using `strptime` rather than `sscanf`